# Search API for the trilogy websites

Tags: feature-request, support, search, api, xml

I was looking at the [Unoffical API documentation for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-stack-overflow-api-reference) on Meta Stack Overflow and I couldn't find a search API. I was working on a code search like utility and would like to utilize results from Stack Overflow and link the results back to Stack Overflow. I can use the OpenSearch API on this URL -  stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms} and get to Stack Overflow, but I was wondering: is there an API where I can get XML results and I can link the results back to Stack Overflow?

I know the data for Stack Overflow is available under Creative Commons, but parsing, indexing, keeping it up to date seems sort of an overkill. A JSON/XML based API would be great.

Comment: Come to think of it, it even falls under the CC licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you also just use the tags query?  It will likely give you more relevant results:
https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/{tagname} (multiple tags can be separated by spaces)

Bing (like Google) is also a possibility using the Bing API 2 for the more general text searches.  You can get JSON, XML, and SOAP for easier processing.  RSS can also be used as a format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251062.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google. It already exists, frequently gives better results than the SO search, is quite up-to-date, and can handle the load.